# building a chat session in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, chat

I wanted to know how using java can i build a `chat` website with as simple concept as [omegle](http://www.omegle.com)? Can anyone please give an insight how does chat session work ? Or how can i do this in java ?

If there are some tutorials that teach this,please link them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I think you can go through the Java Sockets API because socket programming will be the main thing here.

Answer (score 0):

webcam support with java is a difficult topic, maybe you start with plain text chatting

you'll need a gui in an applet or an application (awt,swing) to input and view texts

and you need to transfer your data; for that you should read about TCP and UDP in Java; Sockets are an easy way to implement TCP

Answer (score 0):

this is a classical homework....
You may use different strategies:

- plain sockets as stated in previous answer
- Java RMi for Java 2 Java communication
- JMS for powerful communication

You 'll have to write some specifications to know what kind a chat you want to write:

- just plain text messages
- including video/sound/pictures

HTH